# "printf" only printing variable addresses

Tags: c, printf

so here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int hi;
hi = 3;
printf("%d",&hi);
}
```

and the output is: "2686748"

im using "code blocks" on Windows 7

any ideas whats wrong??

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to print the value of `hi`, just pass it to printf, not its address:

```
printf("%d", hi);
```

You may be confusing `printf` with `scanf`, the latter requiring all of its arguments to be pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The `"%d"` tells the `printf` you are putting in an integer.  The integer you are giving it is `&hi` which is the address of `hi`.  If you want the value of `hi` just use that