# I am getting absurd values for the variable 'credits'

Tags: c, variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
int hist,geo,phy,chem,bio;

int credits=0;


printf("Enter marks in history : ");
scanf("%d",&hist);

if(hist>40)
credits =10;
else
printf("No credits awarded for history");
printf("Credits obtained is %d",&credits);




return(0);

}
```

when I run the code, and I get a value of 230586 for the variable 'Credits'. Please help. I am a beginner in C

Comment: Because you are printing their address...

Comment: You are printing (incorrectly) the address of `credits`.

Comment: Read the documentation of functions you use. Also warnings are not to be ignored, but dealt with properly enable them. If your compiler still does not warn, get a modern compiler. `printf("%d", ...)` does not take a pointer!

Comment: can you please explain by meaning printing incorrectly the address of credits ? @DavidBowling

Comment: @user3934169-- should be `printf("%p", (void *) &credits)`, i.e., you need to use the `%p` specifier to print an address. Note that I am not saying that you want to print the address, only that you are doing so (incorrectly) and that is why you see "absurd values."

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["printf" only printing variable addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959618/printf-only-printing-variable-addresses)

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

`&x` is like asking a question "What is the address of variable `x`?" , that's why you get the strange number.  In order to print the variable value,  please pass `credits` instead of `&credits` to the `printf` function.

```
printf("Credits obtained is %d", credits);
```

Comment: just printf(credits); stops the program

Comment: Please use full format: printf("Credits obtained is %d", credits);